# How to print a string inside of a loop in assembly (MASM)

Tags: string, loops, assembly, masm

So I'm new to assembly, and my professor is far from helpful when it comes to actually explaining what's happening.

In class, we set up loops like this:

```
mov si, 0
mov cx, 5 (repeating the loop 5 times)

L1:
   ...
   loop L1
```

And we print strings like this:

```
mov ah, 40h                 ;write to 
mov bx, handle              ;file
mov cx, lmess2              ;number of bytes to write
mov dx, offset mess2        ;
int 21h
```

So now the issue is that I need to print a string inside the loop. The issue I see with this is that the CX register is used in both the string printing and the loop, so when I try running it, it hangs, as expected.

Is there a different register/method I can use for the loop and the string printing?

Perhaps I can compare the value of the SI register to however many iterations of the loop I want, and then use a JE jump to jump out of the loop? But to me that seems a bit odd.

If anyone could guide me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this that I'm overlooking.

Comment: The simple way is to `push cx` before the print, and `pop` it after.

Comment: I made some little change to my SOLUTION #1. When BP is decremented and becomes zero, the Zero-Flag turns on. JNZ = jump if not zero, so, loop repeats as long as zero-flag is off (BP is not zero yet), and ends when zero-flag goes on (BP is zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions :

**SOLUTION #1**

```
mov si, 0
mov bp, 5  ;DON'T USE CX, USE AN UNUSED REGISTER, LIKE BP.

L1:
   ...
   dec  bp      ;BP - 1. Zero-Flag turns on when BP becomes zero.
   jnz  L1      ;IF BP != 0 JUMP L1. JNZ = jump if last result is not zero.
```

**SOLUTION #2**

```
mov si, 0
mov cx, 5 (repeating the loop 5 times)

L1:
   PUSH CX         ;PRESERVE CX BEFORE IT CHANGES.
   ... ;PRINT HERE.
   POP  CX         ;RESTORE CX FOR PREVIOUS VALUE.
   loop L1
```

The chosen solution depends on the situation : using registers is the fastest way, pushing-popping is slower (because of stack). If you have unused registers, use them, it's faster, if you don't, use stack.