# assembly 8086 loop not working

Tags: assembly, x86-16

i have a function called

```
call print_all
```

i want to loop this say 10 times.

```
mov bx,0
print_again:
call print_all
inc bx
cmp bx,20
jl print_again
```

it doesnt work. why is not comparing. what's wrong.

```
mov al,0
set_1:

complete_print[row_star+0],[col_star+0], star_char,color + 4
call print_star19
call delay_star
call clear
call print_star0
complete_print[row_star+19],[col_star+19], star_char,color + 5
mov currentindex,al
call delay_star
call clear
inc currentindex
mov al,currentindex
cmp al, 5
jl set_1
```

this code doesnt even loop 5 times. :(

```
currentindex db ?

del_star db 20
```

```
delay_star proc
  mov ah, 00
    int 1Ah
    mov bx, dx

jmp_delay:
int 1Ah
sub dx,bx
cmp dl, del_star
jl jmp_delay

ret
delay_star endp
```

complete_print code here:

```
complete_print macro r,c,char,color
mov dh, r ;row
mov dl, c ;column

xor bh,bh
mov ah,02h
int 10h

    mov al, char
    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, color
    mov cx, 1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 10h 
endm
```

Comment: Presumably your registers are modified by the functions you call. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: i tried using other registers, still doesnt work

Comment: Then those functions probably modified the other registers that you tried as well. Place the value of the register on the stack temporarily if you need to preserve it across a function call / interrupt.

Comment: My suggestion would be to move the `mov currentindex,al` line up before the first `call`.

Comment: You say you want to call `print_all` 10 times, but your loop appears to attempt 20 times. Where is `print_all` defined and who defined it? If you don't know that it follows normal x86 calling conventions, then *any* register you wish to preserve you may have to save before you call it.

Comment: What is `complete_print`?

Comment: aw a typo. sorry bout that. just so stressed about the loop.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655190/how-to-print-a-string-inside-of-a-loop-in-assembly-masm/29655297#29655297